# php echo submit button error

Tags: php, javascript, submit

I can't get my css button to submit. the form directs to the correct page, but nothing gets submitted. any ideas?

```
echo "<form action=\"submit_something.php\" id=\"submit_x\" method=\"post\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submit_value\" value\"10\"/><div id=\"button\">
<a href=\"javascript:;\"onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('submit_something').submit()\">buttonvalue</a>
</div></div></form>"
```

update2:

```
echo "<form action=\"submit_something.php\" id=\"submit_x\" method=\"post\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submit_value\" value\"10\"/><div id=\"button\">
<a href=\"javascript:;\"onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('submit_x').submit()\">buttonvalue</a>
</div></div></form>"
```

update3:
I tried this instead:
css:

```
#btn {font-weight:bold}
```

html:

```
<form action="submit_something.php" id="submit_x" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="button" id="#btn">
</form>
```

The button doesn't get styled. I tried differentcss parameters, but the submit button doesn't get styled. Any ideas?

Comment: Look! An element that is **designed** to submit forms: `<input type="submit">`

Comment: i'm using a css button with $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to submit an element with the ID `submit_something`, but your form actually has the ID `submit_x`, so the form won't submit. Also, you shouldn't include `javascript:` into event handler code like `onclick`; this is only needed when you want to execute Javascript code in something like a `href`.

I don't recommend submitting your form using Javascript by the way, avoid it if you can. Using basic HTML functions like submit buttons where possible can prevent a lot of trouble, for example with usability.

Comment: Updated. Still doesn't work. I'm using javascript and onclick because i'm using a css button instead of a regular submit button. I want to use $_POST on a css button. hmmm

Comment: I don't see how this is bad usability? Do you mean if user disables javascript?

Comment: @user1163859: did you also remove the `javascript:` scheme identifier from your event handler? Event handlers like `onclick` are already treated as code, adding an URI scheme will just be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the input type of image instead, or style your submit button, instead of this unmaintainable nastiness you have now.

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.png" />
```

The image input behaves the same way as a regular submit button.

Or, you can style an actual submit button appropriately, with most of the same styles as your anchor currently. For more info, see http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/submit-button/

Comment: Indeed. You really should use the correct controls here, and avoid unnecessary javascript. There's no need to reinvent the wheel for something like a submit button. You will confuse users, and you will destroy usability.

Comment: You gave it an id of "#btn". It should be an id of "btn". The # is for CSS only, and is a way of saying "select by ID".

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="submit" value="button" id="btn">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="button" id="#btn">
```

to apply the style with id btn.

**CSS**

```
#btn {font-weight:bold}
```

and your php to print the form

```
echo "<form action=\"submit_something.php\" id=\"submit_x\" method=\"post\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submit_value\" value=\"10\"/><div id=\"button\">
<a href='' onclick=\"document.getElementById('submit_x').submit();return false;\">buttonvalue</a>
</div></div></form>";
```